# How to solve the error `could not find function "dashboardHeaderPlus"` in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am referring to the R Shiny code in the following Github repository:https://github.com/ganapap1/Dynamic_Filter/blob/main/Multi%20Filter%20Datatable%20with%20SliderInput.R

When I tried to learn more about it, I got the following error. Could someone assist me in resolving this problem?

Error :

```
Error in dashboardHeaderPlus(title = NULL, tags$li(a(splitLayout(cellWidths = c("50%",  : 
  could not find function "dashboardHeaderPlus"
```

Comment: Use `shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader` instead or a shinydashboardPlus version below 2.0.0. See the [breaking changes](https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/news/index.html) for shinydashboardPlus 2.0.0.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, Yes, After editing this code gives me the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected tag to be of type li`